# How to enable "allow-downloads-without-user-activation" from sandbox attribute in Word add-in

Tags: google-chrome, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

We are creating a Word add-in where user can download documents. It worked perfectly fine, although in the console it gave a warning about downloading from an iFrame being deprecated.

After updating Chrome, I now get the following error when trying to download:

> Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the
>   download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more
>   details.

When following the above link, it provides the following information:

> Chrome is planning on removing this capability - i.e. Chrome is going
>   to block all downloads initiated from or instantiated in a sandboxed
>   iframe by default. The embedder may add "allow-downloads" to the
>   sandbox attributes list to opt in. This allows content providers to
>   restrict malicious or abusive downloads.

How can I add "allow-downloads" or "allow-downloads-without-user-activation" to the sandbox attributes in the Word add-in? 
Is there a workaround to enable downloading files?

Comment: Are you testing on Word on the web (formerly Word Online)?

Comment: @RickKirkham, Yes, I'm testing on Word Online.

Comment: I think the task pane in Word Online is an iframe. Does the add-in work if you use Edge or Firefox?

Comment: Also, if you have a Mac, can you test on Safari?

Comment: @RickKirkham, It works on Safari, Firefox, Edge. It doesn't work in EI and Chrome.

Comment: I've discovered that there's a discussion internally in Microsoft about whether to add one or both of these attributes. No decision yet. In the meantime, a workaround that is used to download PDFs in Edge should work in this situation too: It is described at [Get errors trying to download PDF file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#get-errors-trying-to-download-a-pdf-file).

Comment: I see that Microsoft team has added the attribute to iframe. Now it works in Chrome, but still doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @RickKirkham I'm trying to use "Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url)", but I don't see openBrowserWindow method in Office.context.ui. Only displayDialogAsync and taskPaneAction.

Comment: For technical reasons, it is not documented yet and is not in Intellisense. But it is supported in Win32, Mac, iOS; but not Office on the web (aka Office Online).

Comment: UPDATE: The attribute has been added. Please try again and see if it works now.

Comment: It works in Chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: But it's not related to this attribute in iframe. I've found the solution for IE which works for me.
Thank you!